# Change first image in Galleria fullscreen theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, image-gallery, galleria

I need change first image in Galleria fullscreen theme ([link](http://galleria.io/themes/fullscreen/)) after Galleria.run().

For example: I need load 3rd image (sequence of images 3, 4, 5, ...., n, 1, 2, 3)

I can write:

```
jQuery('.galleria-image-nav-right').click().click().click()
```

But It ugly and not user-friendly

Comment: can you please be clear with your question .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `show` method?

```
.show( index )
```

returns Galleria Shows the image specified as index.
 You can call this method anytime and the image will be placed in a
 transition queue.

http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/